# dependent dynamic dropdown list from database jsp

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, sql, jsp

i am trying to make a dropdown list with the second select depending on the first select, and all the information comes from a big database.

These are the two tables and columns i need to use from each with 2 examples.

Table Country: CODE , NAME

```
           RO     ROMANIA

           GB     GREAT BRITAIN
```

Table AREA: CODE,   NAME,   ISOCOUNTRYCODE

```
        RO213   Vrancea     RO

        RO345   Vaslui      RO

        GB365   London      GB

        GB453   Manchester  GB
```

And this is what i curently have in JSP:

```
<td>Ţara în care s-a efectuat prelevarea probei *:</td>
<td>
   <select name="sampcountry" onblur="return validate2(this);" title="Ţara în care a fost prelevata proba (ISO 3166-1-alpha-2).">
      <option value="" />
      <%ResultSet rs1=s t.executeQuery( "select code,name from country"); while(rs1.next()){ %>
         <option value="<%=rs1.getString(" code ")%>">
            <%=rs1.getString( "name")%>
         </option>
         <%}%>
   </select>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
   <td>Zona de prelevare:</td>
   <td>
      <select name="samparea" style="width: 300px" title="Zona în care a fost prelevată proba  (Nomenclatorul Unităţilor Teritoriale pentru Statistică NUTS –  sistem de coduri valabil doar pentru ţările membre UE şi Elveţia).">
         <option value="" />
         <% ResultSet rs2=s t.executeQuery( "select code,name,isocountrycode from area"); while(rs2.next()){ %>
            <option value="<%=rs2.getString(" code ")%>">
               <%=rs2.getString( "name")%>
            </option>
            <%}%>
      </select>
   </td>
</tr>
```

What i need is, when i select the country in the first select box, the second select box will only show the Areas from that country. And the AREA.ISOCOUNTRYCODE column contains the COUNTRY.CODE column information like in the example stated above.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will do the job

```
$("select[name=sampcountry]").on("change", function(){
  $("select[name=samparea] option")
    .hide().removeAttr("selected")
    .parent().find("option[value^="+ $(this).val() +"]").show()
    .first().prop("selected",true);
});
```

This will first hide all options then reveals the one's whichs values start with the selected country code.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3QGEh/)**

Comment: I copied your example in a test page and it works perfectly, but when i try to take it to my page, it doesn't trim the value to just RO from RO234 or just GB from GB343, and the second select just returns the values that are RO or GB. Is it posible to use substring to that jquery? I am new to jquery so i would really apreciate some comments on what some lines do.